# Under what circumstances can a non-null future f throw a NullPointerException on 'f.onComplete(x => println("hello"))'?

Tags: scala

I'm confused about an NPE that I'm getting from the following code snippet:

```
import sys.process._
val context = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val fr = Future {
  Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", cmd).! // some command line command
}(context)
try {
  if (fr == null) {
    println("was null")
  } else {
    println("was not null")
  }
  fr.onComplete(t => println("hello"))
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => println(s"caught: $e")
}
```

Output:

```
was not null
caught: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

EDIT: I understand why there's an NPE now. I need to supply an execution context either implicitly or explicitly to `onComplete`. What I don't understand is why this code compiles as is:

1. If I supply the context manually as in `fr.onComplete(t => println("hello"))(context)` then the code works as expected.
2. If I declare `implicit val context = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`
    then I get a compile error (cannot find implicit execution context for `onComplete`). Why wouldn't this fix the issue?
3. If I change to `import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` then `onComplete` compiles, but `Future { Seq...}` complains about a missing execution context (after I remove the explicitly passed execution context, of course).

Can someone make any sense of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems possible that onComplete is picking up a different implicit ExecutionContext than what you intend, and that implicit context is null. Does this have the same effect?

```
import sys.process._
val context = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val fr = Future {
  Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", cmd).! // some command line command
}(context)
try {
  if (fr == null) {
    println("was null")
  } else {
    println("was not null")
  }
  fr.onComplete(t => println("hello"))(context)
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => println(s"caught: $e")
}
```

Or how about this?

```
import sys.process._
implicit val context = ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val fr = Future {
  Seq("sudo", "sh", "-c", cmd).! // some command line command
}
try {
  if (fr == null) {
    println("was null")
  } else {
    println("was not null")
  }
  fr.onComplete(t => println("hello"))
} catch {
  case e: Throwable => println(s"caught: $e")
}
```